# printing number 6 using nested loops

Tags: java, loops

my cod is supposed to print this:

```
  6666
  6
  6
  6666
  6  6
  6666
```

where as my cod is printing can you find the mistake in mu code:

```
                          6
                          66      6
```

this is my code :

```
if (x == 6)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1 && i == 3 && i == 5)
            for (int k = 1; k <= 4; k++)
                System.out.print(x);
        if (i == 2)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        if (i == 4)
            System.out.print(x + "      " + x);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: pls show complete codE

Comment: I am curious, what wil you do with the output if your code was correct?

Comment: @Ihsan If you look at the output of the cod, it looks like a big 6 consisting of many little 6-es

Comment: Some would say _It's the number of the cod_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here are some hints what your cod should look like:

1. If you write `&&` between two conditions, **all** of them must be true. If you only want one of them to be true, use `||`(inclusive or).
2. If you want a new line to be print out after every run of a loop, write the `System.out.println()` statement inside the loop
3. If you want 2 spaces to be print out, write two spaces and not 6

Your cod is not very wrong at all, and if you use the hints above you should be able to write the correct cod yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have made two errors, as far as I can see.

- The last `System.out.println()` needs to occur for every value of `i`, so it needs to be one line higher up - inside the loop, not outside.
- You should change `if (i == 1 && i == 3 && i == 5)` to `if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5)` because you want this branch to run when `i` is any one of these three values.  It can't simultaneously be all three of them.